# How to completely erase the Photo Library on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, photos, camera

I decided to delete all of my iPhone's photos and videos so I copied everything to iPhoto and deleted everything on my phone. After that, I decided to backup my phone through iTunes. Then I reinstalled iOS 7.1 through iTunes (via ipsw and Restore phone). After a few minutes, I was able to restore everything. The phone is much faster than before. The only problem is, the Photo Library still consumes space.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it the Photo Library or the Camera Roll you want to see as consuming zero bytes on your phone? The screen shot shows Photo Library is not taking up any space.

Comment: @ianc. the Camera Roll is empty as well (watch the video attached to the original question), so the 369 MB are not so easy to explain.

Comment: But the question says "Photo Library" not "Camera Roll" and the two are very different things. Camera Roll will likely always consume space because it needs to have buffer storage for incoming photos and videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos and videos shared through MMS or iMessage take up space. You can delete these to reclaim space from Messages.

<sup>Source: http://forums.everythingicafe.com/threads/iphone-camera-roll-empty-but-storage-2gig.105115/#post-1047178</sup>